# How to configure customized \ref, \pageref in TeX4HT

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib, tex4ht, ref

Is possible to configure the below XML structure for `\ref`, `\pageref` and `natbib` cite commands such as `\citep`, `\citealt` etc.., ?

see Chapter `<xref ref-type="book-part" rid="11">11</xref>`

see Figure `<xref ref-type="fig" rid="fig_ch1_001">1.1</xref>`

`(<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref1">Author, 2000</xref>)`,

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\part{Part Head 1}
\chapter{Chapter Head 1}\label{000}

Sample \ref{000}

\citep{aa}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Author(2000)]{aa}Sample Bib text

\bibitem[Author(2001)]{ab}Sample Bib text

\bibitem[Author(2002)]{ac}Sample Bib text
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```